# Inter-rater reliability against multiple raters

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics

I am conducting inter-rater reliability by doing a clinical test of 25 participants. Can I do the reliability against multiple raters? I mean that I will do the test for all the participants and then the workload will be split between 3 raters. Then I will calculate the inter-rater agreement considering the 3 raters as one rater. Is this an accepted method?
It will be like this
8 participants: rater 1 vs rater 2
,8 participants: rater 1 vs rater 3
,9 participants: rater 1 vs rater 4
.The total will be
25 participants: rater 1 vs rater 2&3&4